# Get <div> name using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, html, attr

```
$("body").click(function() {
       var item = "<h1>You clicked on: #" + $(this).attr('id');
       $(".position").html(item);
     });
```

Why is this giving me a blank response? I want it to identify each HTML object's ID clicked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
$("body").click(function(e) {
       var item = "<h1>You clicked on: #" + $(e.target).attr('id') + "</h1>";
       $(".position").html(item);
     });
```

Answer (score 3):

`this` refers the the object that you registered the handler with, not the original source of the event.
In your case, `this` is always the `<body>`.

You want `e.target`, which refers to the element that directly triggered the event.
(where `e` is the first argument of the handler function)

Comment: It would help to note that `e` would be an argument in the event handler.